# how to reduce white space between header and navigation bar in twitter boostrap using custom css file

Tags: css

there is a white space between header and navigation bar.i want to reduce this white space.IF Any one know how to do this please help me.
this is my html code. i want to reduce that space using custom css file.

```
<div class="container" id="wrapper">
    <h1 id="log">header</h1>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="menu">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


    <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div class="span8" id="left">

        </div>

        <div class="span4" id="right">

        </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Please make jsfiddle.

Comment: Either make a fiddle or post complete code including your CSS

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the margin between the h1 header and the navbar div. Without seeing your css or a link I can't give an exact amount, but try the following and tweak the values to suit. The values can go into negative values if required (eg:  -10px ).

```
#log { margin-bottom: 0; }
#menu { margin-top: 0; }
```